# Saving rmarkdown html files to local drive from shinyapps.io

Tags: html, r, save, r-markdown, shinyapps

I have a shiny app which I have published on **shinyapps.io**.

I am trying to save(download) `html` files that I create using **`rmarkdown`** to a **`local drive`**. I can download pdf, jpeg or png formats. but the reason to save html version is to keep the interactive plots that I have created using plotly and ggplot where I can hover my mouse over data and see values.

After a lot of research, I found out a way to save (upload) the html files to my own dropbox using `drop_upload` function. But it's very inconvenient and not accessible to anyone except me.

So I was wondering if someone could help me with a way to save/download `rmarkdown html` files to a local drive from `shinyapps.io`?